# How to scroll List horizontally in fyne-io/fyne?

Tags: go, fyne

When the list item text is long, I hope the list can scroll horizontally

code example:

```golang
package main
t
import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

var data = []string{"long long long long long long long long long long string", "long long long long long long long long long long string"}

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("List Widget")

    list := widget.NewList(
        func() int {
            return len(data)
        },
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
            return widget.NewLabel("template")
        },
        func(i widget.ListItemID, o fyne.CanvasObject) {
            o.(*widget.Label).SetText(data[i])
        })

    myWindow.SetContent(
        container.NewHScroll(
            list,
        ),
    )
    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

only width of text `widget.NewLabel("template")` scrollable

[image: only width of template scrollable]

List cannot be scrolled

[image: expect scroll]

Answer (score 0):

You’re right the template specifies the sizing for list items. That’s just how it is. Can you make a template that is more indicative of your content?

Scrolling horizontal isn’t really a List feature, perhaps you could try Table? Or set wrapping on your labels and set the item heights accordingly when data loads?

Comment: I'm making a component to display more than 100k lines of log text. Log text is of varying length.


If I set text wrapping and item height, the scrolling will freeze. So I want List to scroll horizontally.


I can only try the Table.

Comment: > If I set text wrapping and item height, the scrolling will freeze

I've never heard of this before, be sure to open a bug on GitHub.

I guess there is an argument for making a list scroll in both directions - maybe we just never thought of it before. Feel free to open that as an issue as well :).